# How to block all traffic for a given user?

Tags: unix, iptables, su, mutt

I'd like to run a script on UNIX with restricted privileges. Specifically, I'd like to run code that I received without letting it send data. My current solution is to:

1. Create a dummy user.
2. Use `iptables` to block all outgoing traffic for the dummy user.
3. Run the target program as the dummy user, using `su - dummy -c 'command'`.

The way I achieve step 2 above is as described in [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47884/how-to-restrict-users-access-to-the-internet-for-time-intervals). Specifically, I use the following command to add a new rule:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner dummy -j DROP
```

When I now try to ping a web address by switching to the dummy account, the ping indeed fails because I added the rule to iptables. Here's that command:

```
> su - dummy -c 'ping www.google.com'
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Same goes for attempting to use `traceroute`. However, when I try to send an email in a similar way using `mutt`, it succeeds:

```
 su - dummy -c 'echo "test" | mutt -s test [emailaddress]'
```

Why doesn't the rule block this, and more generally, how do I ensure all outgoing traffic is blocked for the program I'm running?

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of that web page. I assume there is no way of moving this question over there without reposting though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guide to setting up a chroot jail, which it seems you need.

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot
```

This allows you to control what commands can be executed, you can limit users  access to things like mutt with no problem.  You grant access, you do not have to figure out what to deny.  Because all commands are be default blocked.  This makes setting things up far simpler.

Answer (score 1):

mutt uses a mail server to send the email, and that's most likely not running with the uid of dummy.

Comment: That would make sense only if the mail server were local _and_ the iptables rule, above, didn't apply to local traffic.  (mutt still has to communicate with the mail server.)  You might want to try:  su - dummy -c 'ping 127.0.0.1'  If that works, and your mail server is on the local machine, I'd have to agree with Jorge.

Comment: Pinging localhost works. I'm not sure how I can tell my mail server is on the local machine (I didn't configure mutt in any particular way).

Comment: Besides mutt you have to see if your script is using anything else that might be run/running on a uid other that dummy's and might still keep internet access. mutt is just one example, but you could have more interactions that could pass through.

Comment: As I have no control over which other programs the script might use, I guess it's impossible to achieve such sandboxing this way.

Comment: Have you considered a chroot jail?  That way you CAN control what commands the sandbox will allow.